# Splunk Query - Compute stats by removing duplicates and custom query

Tags: splunk

Need help in writing a splunk query that can help me measure the stats correctly. Please note the data is sometimes sent to splunk more than once sometimes due to an error on our server

Here is an overview . 
I am interested in knowing for how long a user has been using my application. An event will have
user_id, connection state ( values are connected, paused and terminated ), session_length, timestamp. The usage of application for a user can be retrieved from field session_length.

When the user is either in paused or terminated state, it would contain session length value. If the user state contains connected, paused and terminated for a sequence , then the session length should be derived from terminated state, else the session length should be computed from paused state.

Unfortunately the paused and terminated data is sent more than once to the server. I would like to filter such data.

The sample data is written below.

Consideration --> If for a sequence of events for that user , the terminated/paused state is reported twice, then use the oldest session length for that sequence.

Sample Data

```
User1 Terminated session_length=13 timestamp=10.13.
User1 Terminated session_length=11 timestamp=10.11.
User1 Paused     session_length=10 timestamp=10.10
User1 Connected                    timestamp=10.00
--
User1 Paused     session_length=5  timestamp=9.05
User1 Connected                    timestamp=9.00
--
User2 Terminated session_length=13 timestamp=10.13.
User2 Terminated session_length=11 timestamp=10.11.
User2 Paused     session_length=10 timestamp=10.10
User2 Connected                    timestamp=10.00
--
User1 Terminated session_length=6  timestamp=9.06
User1 Connected                    timestamp=8.00
```

--

For the sample data set above, I have used the delimiter -- to filter the sequences and explain how the duration will be calculated.
1) For the User1 ( from top to bottom ), consider the first sequence . User state is connected, paused, terminated,Terminated. So its session length 11 ( consider the earliest reported session length ).
2) For User 1 , sequence 2 , the user state is connected, paused. So its session length - 5
3) For user 2 , sequence 2, the User2 states are connected, paused, terminated, terminated. Its session length - 11.
4) For User 1 , sequence 4 , the user state is connected, terminated. Its session length is 6

The splunk query should report , a sum of session lengths per user which is

User_Id TotalSessionLength
User1    22
User2    11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct solution begins with the [transaction](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Transaction) command:

```
index=my_user_events_index 
 | transaction user_id startswith="connection_state=Connected" unifyends=true
```

This creates a single event for each session, as you grouped them above. Since `transaction` groups all values of the same field name into a single multivalued field, we won't be able to tell which session_length goes with which connection_state. To handle this, we rename the session_length field according to the connection_state before we hit the transaction:

```
index=my_user_events_index 
 | eval paused_session_length=case(connection_state=="Paused",session_length)
 | eval termination_session_length=case(connection_state=="Terminated",session_length)
 | transaction user_id startswith="connection_state=Connected" unifyends=true
```

Almost there! Now we have events that represent a session, each with a multivalued paused_session_length and a multivalued terminated_session_length.  We need to apply our business logic using some creative [multivalue evaluation functions](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/CommonEvalFunctions#Multivalue_functions):

```
index=my_user_events_index 
 | eval paused_session_length=case(connection_state=="Paused",session_length)
 | eval termination_session_length=case(connection_state=="Terminated",session_length)
 | transaction user_id startswith="connection_state=Connected" unifyends=true
 | eval session_length=coalesce(mvindex(mvsort(terminated_session_length),0),mvindex(mvsort(paused_session_length),0))
```

From here, we need only a simple stats command to sum the session lengths by user:

```
index=my_user_events_index 
 | eval paused_session_length=case(connection_state=="Paused",session_length)
 | eval termination_session_length=case(connection_state=="Terminated",session_length)
 | transaction user_id startswith="connection_state=Connected" unifyends=true
 | eval session_length=coalesce(mvindex(mvsort(terminated_session_length),0),mvindex(mvsort(paused_session_length),0))
 | stats sum(session_length) as TotalSessionLength by user_id
```

[Transactions](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Knowledge/Abouttransactions) can be fairly slow with a lot of data, and the multivalued fields are a headache.  Another alternative is to use [streamstats](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Streamstats) by user_id to carry forward the timestamp of the most recent Connected event, then use [stats](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Stats) to aggregate the session and compute the session length.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader (or another SO question) :)

Comment: This is wonderful . Thank you for taking time out to explain . Will try it out and update the answer soon.

Comment: This worked. Instead of using the index=my_user_events_index , I have used sourctype=myapplicationlogs.

Comment: Ryan - One more related question. The event data also contains application_name field. and the user can login to different applications ( its values could be a,b,c etc )  . How can I group the results of this per application_name for each user id. Right now the query is group differnt application data into one sequcne of connected, paused, terminated . I appreciate your response.

Comment: You can just add the application_name to the fields in the transaction command, like so: transaction user_id application_name startswith="connection_state=Connected" unifyends=true

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Ryan. This report is due tomorrow. I appreciate it.

Comment: If I use the application_name the sum stats are remaining blank.I have updated the question again . Posted the question at link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498408/transcation-by-2-fields-does-not-compute-stats  . Appreciate your response.